Outbound Messages Alternatives
I have an org with plenty of outbound messages that mostly use fields from other objects using some formula helper fields. This is a problem as the limit for custom fields is always at maximum and the outbound messages are the only places that are really using these fields nowadays.
Are there any good and easy replacements for outbound messages that do not have this drawback and can use data from other objects? Preferably no-code/low-code as these are mostly built by non-devs to connect to things like Zapier. Worst case I would just try a platform event and some custom Apex code. Let me know if this question is missing something. Thanks!
Edit:
Even without the field drawback, I would like to prevent creating new outbound messages if possible. Mainly since Salesforce does not seem to recommend it anymore:

Use caution if you choose to build with Outbound Messaging

https://architect.salesforce.com/decision-guides/data-integration

You can replace the Outbound Messages with Platform Events in your Org and ask the non-Salesforce side to subscribe to the Platform Events.
Below is the best article about it by Kedar Bhumkar.
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/using-platform-events-replace-outbound-messaging-kedar-bhumkar/
The article talks about using Triggers to fire Platform Events. However, you could also make use of record triggered Flows as No-Code option to fire them based on certain conditions.
Few more links that may be helpful.
Subscribe to Platform Events
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/api_basics/api_basics_streaming
Get Started with Pub/Sub API (with Code Examples)
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/pub-sub-api/guide/intro.html

I like the idea. Now I must figure out how to use this as a replacement in a Zapier context.

Your answer is valuable and as close as it gets - the rest I will figure out on my own. Thanks for your contribution and welcome to Stack Overflow!
